# Can you access the web server logs from an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to access referrer information from the server log in a ASP.NET web application?

I would like to know if a customer comes to my web app from a specific site and change the app's behavior accordingly.  I could have the webmaster of the other site include a query string, but to my knowledge this wouldn't work because as soon as Tom, Dick or Harry posted the link somewhere else, the query string would be unreliable.

Is there a sure fire way for a web app to know where the user came from?

Comment: You might find Google Analytics the easiest way of seeing your referrers. 90% will probably be google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you not just access the Request host header for the HTTP_REFERER instead of the log file? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx), but note that you are never guaranteed to recieve this information, nor is it reliable if you do.

Comment: I guess even in the logs it is unreliable.  Never thought about that.

Comment: In addition, many logs are cached, so the information you're looking for may not be written to disk until well after the request is done.

Comment: Well the information is derived from the request headers which are ultimately entirely up to the client to create, so very easy to forge and very easy to drop altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just check the [`Request.UrlReferer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property and change the behavior if the referer is not any page on your site?

This would be a lot simpler than referencing IIS logs.

Comment: That's for creating a WebRequest - you want HttpRequest.UrlReferer for seeing where a user came from ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the referrer information through the [HttpRequest.UrlReferer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) object.

However you should note:

1. This can null - so check for null before calling AbsoluteUri on it.
2. This can be changed fairly easily, so you can't rely on it completely

Comment: Actually it can be considerably worse than null, it's very frequently "Replaced by Anti-spyware Program X" which is obviously also not a URL and consequently throws an exception. Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
```

gives you the same as the server logs will. Probably a combo of querystring variable and UrlReferrer will do the best job of ensuring that it came from the right source.

UrlReferrer is sent by the client, and it's not guaranteed to be there.

Comment: And can be null (or other nasty things) if a user typed in the URL directly, clicked a bookmark, etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a shared environment? Normally they will supply this if you request the logs (normally an option in Plesk or similar). The log directory will probably be one or two folders up from the root http folder, so it may not be accessible using the IIS user.

On a dedicated server then you can obviously configure this manually.

Comment: It is dedicated.  Would there be a way using code to access that info on the fly?   Seems hairy at best, because I guess you would have to parse the log, now that I think about it.

Comment: I need to read the fine print in these questions instead of the body and the question title; I would make a useless lawyer

Comment: @Jim - Note that the logs aren't guaranteed to be written to instantly - I've noticed that under load it can take a few minutes for a request to actually be written to the logs, even though the time-stamp for the entry will be accurate.